# Icon without app name in Notifications (iOS 9.2)

Tags: ios, notifications

There is an icon without app name in the Notifications screen of my iPhone (iOS 9.2).

Any idea what app may be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the [Apple News](http://www.apple.com/news/) app icon.

It should appear normally if you are [in a region that is supported by Apple News](http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#news).

Its availability is dictated by the `Region` setting under `Settings > General > Language & Region`.

If that is set to a region that is supported by Apple News, then it is likely a bug. Try rebooting your device.

If that is not set to a region that is supported, the malformed entry in your Notifications settings may be a result of having used one of several 'methods' to force the availability of Apple News.

It should not present any problems for your device, but if you really want it fixed/removed, a restore may be in order.

Comment: Yes, it is the Apple News icon indeed. I am in a country where Apple News is not supported yet so I don't have it installed, but my Language and Region settings are set to UK (where Apple News is supported), which may be causing it.